# IOBluetoothHandsFreeDevice audio static

Tags: macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am attempting to implement a bluetooth hands free profile under OS X 10.10 using IOBluetoothHandsFreeDevice.  I can connect and control my iPhone 6 running iOS 8.2 without issues.

Every **first** attempt to make or receive a call (or use Siri) results in static noise being streamed from my phone to my computer instead of audio.  The static doesn't appear to be completely random as it is in sync with the sound I expect to hear (e.g.  ringing tone, etc).  The audio from my Mac to my iPhone is however crystal clear.

After the initial static audio call, making another call using the same connection yields 50/50 results, half the calls perfect, and the other half being static.

Here's the basic code:

```
IOBluetoothDevice* device = ...;
_hfDevice = [[IOBluetoothHandsFreeDevice alloc] initWithDevice:device delegate:self];
uint32_t supportedFeatures = _hfDevice.supportedFeatures;
supportedFeatures |= IOBluetoothHandsFreeDeviceFeatureEnhancedCallStatus;
supportedFeatures |= IOBluetoothHandsFreeDeviceFeatureEnhancedCallControl;
supportedFeatures |= IOBluetoothHandsFreeDeviceFeatureCLIPresentation;
[_hfDevice setSupportedFeatures:supportedFeatures];
[_hfDevice connect];

// after connected delegate method...

// dial a phone number
const NSString* phoneNumber = @"...";
[_hfDevice dialNumber:phoneNumber];

// or activate siri
const NSString* activateSiri = @"AT+BVRA=1";
[_hfDevice sendATCommand:activateSiri];
```

I expect that I'm possibly overlooking something, but Apple's documentation on their bluetooth code doesn't contain any examples for creating hands free applications.  Has anyone else had this experience?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved in an update to OS X